# Implementing polymorphic Java interfaces with specific types

Tags: java

I want to implement the `Map<K,V>` interface, but I want to constrain `K` to type `String`.

Is this possible? Or does the interface definition impose that `K` be polymorphic?

If it is possible, could someone help with the class signature, tks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try : `class Test< V > implements Map< String, V >`
hope it helps

Comment: Ah, got it. I was doing: class Test< String, V > implements Map< String, V >. I can see my mistake now, tks

Answer (score 2):

No problem:

```
public class YourMap implements Map<String, Object> { /* ... */ }
```

If the class should be generic you can do:

```
public class YourMap<K extends String,V> implements Map<K, V> { /* ... */ }
```

But since `String` is final (as @Peter Lawrey commented), you might as well just do:

```
public class YourMap<V> implements Map<String, V> { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: A good example, though String is final and tricky to extends ;)

Comment: The compiler doesn't sanity check these things :~, like extending a final class or <? super Object>.